# Поиск по сообщениям discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

Как я могу осуществить поиск сообщений по отдельному содержанию, в отдельном канале?
Возможно ли это вообще?
JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Эта возможность доступна только для клиента. В боте вы можете получить последние 100 сообщений в канале и уже отфильтровать их по вашим параметрам.

```js
channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 })
  .then(messages => console.log(`Received ${messages.size} messages`))
  .catch(console.error);
```